# How to deploy many applications with subdomains in AWS? Which config should I use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-route53, mern

I'm new to AWS and deployment. Here's my doubt.

I've a domain, let's say **[www.company.com](http://www.company.com)**. I've 3 apps to deploy,

1. NodeJS Backend (**api.clientName.company.com**)
2. React Marketplace (**clientName.company.com**)
3. React Admin Panel (**admin.clientName.company.com**)

So I'll customize as per clients requirements and deploy like **clientName.company.com**.

What config should I use for many clients? Now I got 5 more new clients. Can I create only one EC2 instance and manage all clients apps together? Also can I migrate my domains to route53 so that I can create unlimited subdomains?

Can anyone explain my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can manage multiple applications on single EC2 instance, but make sure the instance size is large enough to withstand the traffic.

You can achieve this by using Laravel Forge in which you can deploy Laravel and simple PHP Applications as well. It just makes things easier to manage.

If you not comfortable using Laravel Forge you can use Filezilla too.

It is better if you migrate domains into Route53 as it will be easier to manage and everything will be in one place.
You can create the subdomains as you like and map it to the EC2 instances Elastic IP, make sure you attach an EIP so that the IP address does not change after a reboot.

Comment: That sounds better

Comment: You can manage multiple applications on a single EC2 instance, but they would all be on the same IP adress, they would only listen to different ports. You can configure your DNS provider to map all the (sub)domains to that same IP adress but to then reach the correct application you would need to specify the port number, which is something you probably dont want, because then the url would look like admin.clientName.company.com:8080 (you can only have one of them on port 443).

If you really want all your applications on one ec2 instance you should use a reverse proxy, like Nginx or Apache.